# Validation on Jpassword and Jtextfields? - Stopping symbol or greater than 10 character entry? How

Tags: java, regex, swing, passwords

I know you can use regex commands or if statements to compare data input against a white or black list but I'd like to actually like to deny symbol input all together. Similarly deny the input of greater than 10 characters into the text or password field.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: One way: use a DocumentFilter. If you search this site, you can find more information on this and example programs, some written by me.

Comment: You could use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) to validate the input in real time, rejecting input as the user makes it. [For more examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)